# Highchart and HTMLCanvas

Tags: highcharts, extjs4, html2canvas

I have multiple charts (highcharts) placed in extjs panel component.
I want to download all the charts and extjs component in a div as image. 
I used html canvas and it downloads only the extjs component. The highchart components are not captured in the image. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Agi La I don't know extjs, but since I had problems in dowloading highcharts charts too, I'll explain what I did to get them.

First, make sure you have the **rgbcolor.js** and **canvg.js** libraries.

Second, you can use this script to make an AJAX call:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            var svg = document.getElementById('$this->id_chart').children[0].innerHTML;
            canvg(document.getElementById('$this->id_canvas'),svg);
            var img = $this->id_canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //img is data:image/png;base64
            img = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'AJAX/AJAX1.php', 
              data: {INFO1: img , INFO2: '$this->file_name_export' }                   
            });
        });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/rgbcolor.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/canvg.js'></script>

<!-- canvas tag to convert SVG -->
<canvas id='$this->id_canvas' style='display:none;'></canvas>
```

Where $this->id_chart is the id of the div where you're placing the highchart and $this->file_name_export is the name you want to give to your saved chart.

And in your Ajax file you must have:

```
$img        = $_POST['INFO1'];
$fileName   = $_POST['INFO2']. '.jpeg';

$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

if ($im !== false) {
    // Save image in the specified location
    imagejpeg($im, "../temp/" .$fileName,100);
    imagedestroy($im);               
}
```

You can see [here](http://www.blog.openshell.in/2014/08/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-highcharts-on-the-server/) the original source, that uses this code in a button instead of an automatic download like mine.